# Regular expression complex combination : (^ +)|( +$)

Tags: r, regex, analytics

Considering myself a novice at Regular-Expressions, I came across an R-script which would eventually wipe away ***white-spaces*** from a string or (say) a line using ***gsub()***.
Following is the *gsub()* function with a (in my opinion) a complex criterion to match :

```
gsub("(^ +)|( +$)", "", line)
```

Can anyone explain me what does this expression mean ? Thoroughly !

An example would make this so easy.

Please also provide some links where i can learn some real stuff about ***regex***, because i found no good sources when i looked for the same.

Thanks for considerations.

Comment: The parentheses (capturing groups in regex) aren't doing anything in this usage; you could just use `gsub('^ +| +$', '', '  foo  ')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex just trims the space in the string, Using the base R function `trimws` will be more clear I think.

---

`(^ +)|( +$)`

1. `^` string start position.
2. `+`(space plus) more than one space.
3. `$` string ending position.
4. `|` alternative.

Comment: Believe it or not, the base `trimws()` function is actually slower. The difference is small, but hashir's regex is 4-5 times faster. Check out the results here: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=6QFS7LaX

Comment: @AndrewBrēza Thanks, I will edit my answer.  It seems `trimws` is written in pure R using `sub` internally, rather than C which I believe to be.

Comment: That test is too small to be meaningful. If you resample up to a vector of 10k or so, `trimws` is about twice as fast. Depending on your version of R, adding `perl = TRUE` will make them roughly equal, as it now gets JIT compiled (mostly).

Comment: Side note: It's a bad idea to name a parameter (or anything) `list`, particularly if it doesn't actually take a list.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza Have you tested this case `rep("text       ", 1000)`? Depending on how the regex engine is implemented, it might be significantly slower.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys. Can anyone throw some light on how `(+)` works differently when put after and before ? Specially with `(^)` and `($)`.

Comment: Excellent points all around. I completely agree that using `list` as a variable name was a mistake and that `trimws` can be faster at scale.

Comment: @alistaire This thread made me curious so I put together a script to compare the speed of the two functions with different sizes of input. I haven't gotten the results to run in R Fiddle but it works for me locally and the conclusion is that `trimws()` is faster once `n` exceeds 1500.
http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=LhL0UuyE